# too many re-renders , infinite re-renderes

Tags: reactjs

Why does this causes infinite re-renderers when I invoke `setPost` using `usePost hook` from the parent component (Post) ? What causes the error?

```
function Post({ activePostId }) {
  const { status, post, setPost, error, refetch } = usePost(activePostId)
  const [savePost, savePostStatus] = useSavePost()

  setPost('SetPost')

  const onSubmit = async (values) => {
    try {
      await savePost(values)
      refetch()
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err)
    }
  }
```

```
export default function usePost(postId) {
  const [post, setPost] = React.useState()
  const [error, setError] = React.useState()
  const [status, setStatus] = React.useState('loading')

  const refetch = async () => {
    try {
      setStatus('loading')

      const post = await axios
        .get(`/api/posts/${postId}`)
        .then((res) => res.data)

      setPost(post)
      setError()
      setStatus('success')
    } catch (err) {
      setError(err)
      setStatus('error')
    }
  }

  React.useEffect(() => {
    refetch()
  }, [])

  return {
    post,
    setPost,
    status,
    error,
    refetch,
  }
}
```

Comment: Please create a [mcve]

Comment: You're calling a state setter in the body of a functional component. When the component rerenders from the set state call it will call the state setter again... you get the idea. Don't do that.

Comment: alright, so even when using a custom hook, it will re-render the component where it is invoked. am I right? in this case in Post component

Comment: Yes. I see this a lot with custom hooks, people seem to think there is something magic about them. The only special thing that React does with custom hooks is memoise the return internally between renders, like you would expect from its own internal hooks. Otherwise it's exactly the same as if the code were in the original component's body.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`setPost` changes the `post` value in your hook, which is consumed by your component. This triggers a re-render, thus causing and infinite loop.

To work around this, you would want to call `setPost` only a limited number of times. You could fix your example by using a `useEffect` to call it only at startup.

```
function Post({ activePostId }) {
  const { status, post, setPost, error, refetch } = usePost(activePostId)
  const [savePost, savePostStatus] = useSavePost()

  useEffect(() => {
    setPost('SetPost')
  }, []); // <- the empty array here ensures that the setPost is called once, if you want it called on other dependency changes, you can add them here.
  
  const onSubmit = async (values) => {
    try {
      await savePost(values)
      refetch()
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err)
    }
  }
```